# Python - Searching multiple values in list and performing multiple operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search

I'm trying to search a list I have for specific values and if any of those values exist in the list, I would like to perform a different operation.

Currently this is the list I am working with:

```
print(categories)
['Creams', 'Bath', 'Personal Care']
```

What I would like to do is search this categories list for some different values. To do this, I've converted `categories` into a set and am individually searching for each of the values with an if statement.

For example:

```
c = set(categories)
if "Conditioners" in c:
     print("1")
if "Bath" in c: 
     print("2")
if "Shaving Gels" in c:
     print("3")
```

Which returns:

```
2
```

What I would ideally like to do is put my criteria into a list or some other relevant data structure and have it perform that particular operation if that value exists within `categories` in an efficient manner.

Comment: why not have the keywords in a dictionary that maps to functions that execute on the categories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store your functions in dictionary, where values are desired functions. That way, you have easy access to them by keys and you can traverse categories normally:

```
categories = ['Creams', 'Bath', 'Personal Care']

my_dict = {
    'Conditioners': lambda: print(1),
    'Bath': lambda: print(2),
    'Shaving Gels': lambda: print(3)
}


for category in categories:
    fn = my_dict.get(category, lambda: None)
    fn()
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Would you happen to know how I could do a different function if in the `categories` list, two or more of the keys in `my_dict` values as opposed to each individual function?

Comment: @express_v2 That's a little bit more complicated and the answer is long for comments. Feel free to open new question.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, this is what you're looking for. `dict comprehension` with `enumerate`. This will also reduce the amount of manual labor required so long as your list is in the order you want.

```
d = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(categories,1)}
d
{'Creams': 1, 'Bath': 2, 'Personal Care': 3}
```

You can perform whatever operation you want on the dictionary.

```
c = ['Conditioners','Bath','Shaving Gels']
for i in c:
    print (d.get(i, None))
None
2
None
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a dictionary would be a suitable datatype. You could complete your task like such.

```
diction = {"Conditioners": 1, "Bath": 2} #add whatever else you want

for item in categories:
        try:
           print(diction[item])
        except:
            continue
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest another neat and maintainable alternative to dictionaries. You could also create a class with `@staticmethod` and use `getattr` to call methods like so,

```
categories = ['Creams', 'Bath', 'Personal Care']

class CategoriesWorker:
    @staticmethod
    def Creams():
        print(1)
    @staticmethod
    def Bath():
        print(2)
    @staticmethod
    def PersonalCare():
        print(3)

for category in categories:
    try:
        getattr(CategoriesWorker, category.replace(" ", ""))()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

>>>
1
2
3
```

Note here that naming of your `@staticmethod`s is crucial. I basically use a the same value without spaces and then `strip` them of the actual value in the list to retrieve it in the class.

---

Basically, I suggested this in order to overcome the problem where using a dictionary in conjunction with lambdas could lead to unreadable code. Indeed, your specific example ask to simply `print()` values. But what if the logic of the methods was more complicated ? You'd be writing a unreadable dictionary fast enough.

Now, an alternative you be to wrap the logic in a method and use it in a dictionary.

```
categories = ['Creams', 'Bath', 'Personal Care','test']
def Creams():
  print(1)

def Bath():
  print(2)

def PersonalCare():
  print(3)

comparison_dict = {'Creams':Creams,'Bath':Bath,'Personal Care':PersonalCare}


for category in categories:
  comparison_dict.get(category, lambda: None)()

>>>>
1
2
2
```

That would be valid also. I just like the class definition better since it is clear what this class intends to do and I like to have related code at one compact emplacement.

Answer (score 0):

```
categories = ['Creams', 'Bath', 'Personal Care']
criteria = {"Conditioners" : "1", "Bath" : "2", "Shaving Gels" : "3"}

# loop through all the categories
for i in set(categories):
    # if the category is in the criteria print the value
    if i in criteria.keys():
        print(criteria[i]) #print 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (for the exact case you put above)

```
a=['Creams', 'Bath', 'Personal Care']
b=['Conditioners','Bath','Shaving Gels']
[print(c-1) for c,e in b if e in enumerate(a)]
```